# ngModule Errors when I compile

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an angular app that is using Angular Material, specifically MatTooltip module. When I try to compile the app using ng serve, I get the following error

```
ERROR in MatTooltipModule is not an NgModule
```

but when I go back to the file and add a space or save the same file causing it to recompile, the error is gone and it compiles. Because of this, I don't believe that it is a problem with how I am importing it into my app.

Currently these are my dependancies

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "4.1.3",
}
```

I am not sure if it is a compatibility error between my dependencies or not.

```js
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';

imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTooltipModule,]
```

Comment: If you do a `ng build --prod` does it build without errors?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel no, I get the following error ERROR in Unexpected value 'MatTooltipModule in /Users/strypeez/Dropbox/gosco-webNEW/gosco-webUPTODATE/node_modules/angular/material/tooltip/typings/index.d.ts' imported by the module 'AppModule in /Users/strypeez/Dropbox/gosco-webNEW/gosco-webUPTODATE/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a NgModule annotation.

Comment: What is the actual version of `@angular/material` installed? (not what `package.json` lists, but what is actually installed in your `node_modules` folder)

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Under which file can I see what version it is?

Comment: If you have npm v5+ you can look in your `package-lock.json` file for the version of everything installed. Additionally you can run `npm list --depth 0` to see the version of your dependencies listed in your `package.json` file (regardless of npm version)

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel its version 2.0.0-beta.12